# Django - Associated OneToOne Record not being deleted

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have these models.  The problem is that when I delete a dog record using Django Admin the associated collar record is not being deleted.

I'm on Django 1.2.  I thought cascade delete was the default.  It it an issue with Collar being linked to a legacy table?

Much thanks in advance.

```
class Collar(models.Model):
    serial_number =  models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='serial_number')
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'existing_table_from_before_django_was_born'

class Dog(models.Model):
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    collar = models.OneToOneField(Collar,blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an issue of the connection to a legacy table. The cascade deletion will work of you delete the Collar object, then the related Dog object will be deleted (probably if you remove blank=True, null=True).

To delete Collar after deletion of Dog you need to overload the delete method of Dog.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking backwards for some reason.

Comment: So if I override the delete method to first delete the collar record and then delete itself, do I need to somehow wrap the delete method in a transaction (or does Django 1.2 do that automatically?).  I want to avoid any cases where the collar record would get deleted but then hit an error before the Dog record was also deleted.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/transactions/#django-db-transaction-commit-on-success

Answer (score 2):

You have to think about the relationships and *why* the delete cascade exists. The FK is on `Dog` (the field is in its table in the DB). If you delete `Dog`, it just deletes `Dog`. There's no need to delete anything else. However, if you delete `Collar`, then you *may* end up with an issue with referential integrity if the the `Dog` that associates with it is not also deleted. In your case here, the field is NULL-able, so you could simply set the collar field to NULL and fix the referential integrity problem, but in other scenarios, the `Dog` would *have* to be deleted to maintain database integrity.

The delete cascade often ends up being very handy, but it's important to remember that the goal of it is not to make your life simpler, but rather to preserve database integrity. As a result, there's no motivation to clean up the opposite end of the relationship (deleting `Collar` when you delete `Dog`) because no problems will result from that.